# Rewriting $P(|X|>x,|Y|>y)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

I want to calculate a probability distribution of the form $P(|X|>x,|Y|>y)$, and I want to hear if someone can confirm the following since the last expression would be easier to calculate:
$$
\begin{aligned}
P(|X|>x,|Y|>y) & =P(X \notin[-x,+x], Y \notin[-y,+y]) \\
& =1-\{P(X \in[-x,+x])+P(Y \in[-y,+y])-P(X \in[-x,+x], Y \in[-y,+y]\}
\end{aligned}
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the last expression and first expression are equivalent